# Setting a "statical" running of MS DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, microsoft

I am trying to setup a MS DHCP server that runs in some kind of "statical assignment" mode.

The goal is that prevent clients automatically receiving IP configuration from DHCP. I want them only receiving configuration, after DHCP reservation set for their devices. The key should be somehow the MAC address of the authorization.

I tried some solutions, such as adding exclusion range that is same as the distribution range, but I don't think that is much "practical".

I also tried to make NPS or scope level policies, but without any success.

MAC address filtering could be also a solution, but I want to rather stick with something that is involved with DHCP reservation.

So, any suggestions what could be the best solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible for Windows but I did a similar thing on CISCO by allocating a sufficiently low pool so that non-reserved DHCP addresses do not have anything left to get.

Comment: Pretty sure it can be done by NPS. I just couldn't find any arcticle about it.

Comment: There's a complete guide of using NAP (Network Access Protection)   here: http://blog.windowsserversecurity.com/2011/04/18/network-access-protection-with-dhcp-step-by-step-guide/  ; it may be of help.